# Julia, syntax to use @views in a function

Tags: function, iteration, julia

I would like to build a function, that iterates through values of a Julia "zip" file and substitutes some values in a large 3d array.  In a previous help someone wise suggested the use of `@view` and I quite like the idea of writing back to the original section of the array rather than making a copy.  If this is good method (happy to take advice), I can't figure out the correct syntax for the function, that exploits `@view`.  This is a demo:

Original code, which works well, will be many more in final application

```
(@view Pop[end, :, 1])[findall(x -> x==33, Pop[end, :, 1])] .= 3
(@view Pop[end, :, 1])[findall(x -> x==44, Pop[end, :, 1])] .= 4
```

It simply substitutes 33 -> 3, and 44 -> 4 in the array `Pop[end, :, 1]`

So I produce the zip file:

```
Orig = [44, 33];
NewS = [4 , 3];
ResetZip = zip(Orig,NewS)
```

Then produce the function:

```
## Function to reset status numbers back from 44 and 33 to 4 and 3
function ResetState(Arr1, Orig, NewS)
    Arr1[findall(x -> x==Orig, Arr1)] .= NewS
end
```

Then try to execute the function iteratively over values of `ResetZip`

```
for (Orig, NewS) = ResetZip
    ResetState(@view (Pop[end, :, 1]), Orig, NewS)
end
```

but I get this error

```
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Invalid use of @view macro: argument must be a reference expression A[...].
```

So I've got something wrong in the syntax.  My question is, where do I put the `@view` to get the syntax correct, to be able to use it, and iterate over values of the zip file?  Thx. J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@MattB.'s answer explains the macro issue, but you are severely over-complicating things in the first place. There is no need to use the `@view` macro like this. Instead of

```
(@view Pop[end, :, 1])[findall(x -> x==33, Pop[end, :, 1])] .= 3
```

you can write

```
Pop[end, findall(x -> x==33, Pop[end, :, 1]), 1] .= 3
```

But that's too complicated too. Instead of this, you can write

```
Pop[end, Pop[end, :, 1].==33, 1] .= 3
```

But this is also needlessly complicated. What you really should do is to use the `replace!` function. Though, then you have to use `view`s again:

```
replace!(@view(Pop[end, :, 1]), 3=>33)
```

And now you can even do both replacements at the same time:

```
replace!(@view(Pop[end, :, 1]), 33=>3, 44=>4)
```

Comment: `Pop[end, :, 1].==33` could still benefit from `@views` somewhere in front, or `@view(Pop[end, :, 1]).==33`. But `@view(Pop, end, :, 1)` inside `replace!` won't work, the macro needs to act on an indexing expression. Or else the function `view(Pop, 100, :, 1)` takes these arguments but won't accept `end`.

Comment: To the final solution, I get the following error, as suggested by mcabbot `julia> replace!(@view(Pop, end, :, 1), 33=>3, 44=>4) ERROR: syntax: unexpected "end" `  Have I done something wrong?   So do we have a solution that will do multiple replacements, in one line of code, outwith the use of a function?

Comment: @JimMaas See the edit I just made.  The `@view` macro requires an indexing expression.

Comment: I cannot see now what edit has been made, but I was positive that I checked that I only used `end` with the macro form and with indexing brackets, because I did it wrong at first and then fixed it.. Weird.

Comment: That seems to work great, very simple and elegant, thanks  a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a quirk of macro parsing in general. You can either separate a macro's arguments by spaces or you can treat it like a function call.  You've written:

```
ResetState(@view (Pop[end, :, 1]), Orig, NewS)
```

That space between `@view` and `(Pop...` means that you've chosen the space-separated mechanism.  And the macro will happily "gobble up" all the other arguments that you intended for `ResetState`.  In other words, you're effectively passing a *tuple* to `@view`. If I ask Julia to simply "quote" the expression you can see how it prints out — and it does so with explicit parentheses that make it more obvious:

```
julia> quote
         ResetState(@view (Pop[end, :, 1]), Orig, NewS)
       end
quote
    #= REPL[5]:2 =#
    ResetState(#= REPL[5]:2 =# @view((Pop[end, :, 1], Orig, NewS)))
end
```

The fix?  Delete that space and call the macro like a function whenever you use it inside a function call:

```
ResetState(@view(Pop[end, :, 1]), Orig, NewS)
```

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Just learning Julia coming from R, so didn't realise that white space made any difference, lesson learned, really appreciated. Quote function will be useful.

Comment: Yes, there are a handful of places where whitespace is significant — macros are one.